# Add multiple pages to flexdashboard storyboard

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I'm trying to create a [flexdashboard storyboard](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/layouts.html#storyboard), but with [multiple pages](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/using.html#multiple-pages). So that I can display two storyboards in the same Rmd.

To better explain, here is a reprex dashboard (`Rmd`) adapted from the standard [flexdashboard storyboard](https://testing-apps.shinyapps.io/flexdashboard-storyboard/) template:

````
---
title: "Example Storyboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    social: menu
    source: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

### Leaflet is a JavaScript library for creating dynamic maps that support panning and zooming along with various annotations.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("wt", "hp")])
```

***

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/

- Interactive panning/zooming

- Compose maps using arbitrary combinations of map tiles, markers, polygons, lines, popups, and GeoJSON.

- Create maps right from the R console or RStudio

- Embed maps in knitr/R Markdown documents and Shiny apps

- Easily render Spatial objects from the sp package, or data frames with latitude/longitude columns

- Use map bounds and mouse events to drive Shiny logic


### d3heatmap creates interactive D3 heatmaps including support for row/column highlighting and zooming.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("disp", "drat")])
```

***

https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap/

- Highlight rows/columns by clicking axis labels

- Click and drag over colormap to zoom in (click on colormap to zoom out)

- Optional clustering and dendrograms, courtesy of base::heatmap
````

This works as intended, and looks like the following:

[image: initial dashboard setup]

I then tried to add **multiple pages** (i.e., **Page 1**, and **Page 2**) using the [flexdashboard syntax](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/layouts.html#multiple-pages) (so that the navigation pane has separate storyboards) as follows:

````
---
title: "Example Storyboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    social: menu
    source: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Page 1
=====================================  

### Leaflet is a JavaScript library for creating dynamic maps that support panning and zooming along with various annotations.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("wt", "hp")])
```

***

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/

- Interactive panning/zooming

- Compose maps using arbitrary combinations of map tiles, markers, polygons, lines, popups, and GeoJSON.

- Create maps right from the R console or RStudio

- Embed maps in knitr/R Markdown documents and Shiny apps

- Easily render Spatial objects from the sp package, or data frames with latitude/longitude columns

- Use map bounds and mouse events to drive Shiny logic


### d3heatmap creates interactive D3 heatmaps including support for row/column highlighting and zooming.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("disp", "drat")])
```

***

https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap/

- Highlight rows/columns by clicking axis labels

- Click and drag over colormap to zoom in (click on colormap to zoom out)

- Optional clustering and dendrograms, courtesy of base::heatmap


Page 2
=====================================  

### Leaflet is a JavaScript library for creating dynamic maps that support panning and zooming along with various annotations.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("wt", "cyl")])
```

***

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/

- Interactive panning/zooming

- Compose maps using arbitrary combinations of map tiles, markers, polygons, lines, popups, and GeoJSON.

- Create maps right from the R console or RStudio

- Embed maps in knitr/R Markdown documents and Shiny apps

- Easily render Spatial objects from the sp package, or data frames with latitude/longitude columns

- Use map bounds and mouse events to drive Shiny logic


### d3heatmap creates interactive D3 heatmaps including support for row/column highlighting and zooming.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("disp", "drat")])
```

***

https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap/

- Highlight rows/columns by clicking axis labels

- Click and drag over colormap to zoom in (click on colormap to zoom out)

- Optional clustering and dendrograms, courtesy of base::heatmap
````

However, this results in the following:

[image: multiple pages has issues with storyboard]

As it can be seen, the multiple pages (i.e., **Page 1**, and **Page 2**) are created, but the storyboard layout is disrupted dramatically. Could anyone please help show how to get multiple pages working with (multiple) storyboards in a single browser?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that for multiple pages, there is a separate feature called [storyboard pages](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/using.html#storyboard-pages), which achieves the required outcome.

So to achieve this, first the global storyboard is removed and replaced with this `yaml` header:

```
---
title: "Example Storyboard"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
```

And then we simply add the `{.storyboard}` to each Page heading, e.g.

```
Page 1 {.storyboard}
=====================================
```

So for completeness, the full [storyboard pages](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/using.html#storyboard-pages) reprex is as follows:

````
---
title: "Example Storyboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    # storyboard: true
    social: menu
    source: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Page 1 {.storyboard}
=====================================  

### Leaflet is a JavaScript library for creating dynamic maps that support panning and zooming along with various annotations.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("wt", "hp")])
```

***

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/

- Interactive panning/zooming

- Compose maps using arbitrary combinations of map tiles, markers, polygons, lines, popups, and GeoJSON.

- Create maps right from the R console or RStudio

- Embed maps in knitr/R Markdown documents and Shiny apps

- Easily render Spatial objects from the sp package, or data frames with latitude/longitude columns

- Use map bounds and mouse events to drive Shiny logic


### d3heatmap creates interactive D3 heatmaps including support for row/column highlighting and zooming.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("disp", "drat")])
```

***

https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap/

- Highlight rows/columns by clicking axis labels

- Click and drag over colormap to zoom in (click on colormap to zoom out)

- Optional clustering and dendrograms, courtesy of base::heatmap


Page 2 {.storyboard}
=====================================  

### Leaflet is a JavaScript library for creating dynamic maps that support panning and zooming along with various annotations.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("wt", "cyl")])
```

***

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/

- Interactive panning/zooming

- Compose maps using arbitrary combinations of map tiles, markers, polygons, lines, popups, and GeoJSON.

- Create maps right from the R console or RStudio

- Embed maps in knitr/R Markdown documents and Shiny apps

- Easily render Spatial objects from the sp package, or data frames with latitude/longitude columns

- Use map bounds and mouse events to drive Shiny logic


### d3heatmap creates interactive D3 heatmaps including support for row/column highlighting and zooming.

```{r}
plot(mtcars[, c("disp", "drat")])
```

***

https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap/

- Highlight rows/columns by clicking axis labels

- Click and drag over colormap to zoom in (click on colormap to zoom out)

- Optional clustering and dendrograms, courtesy of base::heatmap
````

This results in the intended output, as seen below:

[image: correct storyboard pages layout]